# Is it safe to use a dryer that’s been sitting outside for almost 2 years?

Tags: dryer

we have a dryer that’s been sitting outside for roughly two years, it’s not covered at all and has been exposed to pretty much every element, bug/rodent in our area. My husband wants to bring it in, clean it up and use it for our son’s room. Just asking for some extra opinions or advice since he isn’t doing much research on how to even clean/fix a dryer.

Comment: as long as it was sitting and not standing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be deemed safe.

This will likely require removing the rear cover and inspecting the electrical and clearing any debris from the intake and exhaust vents.

As long as there is no damage to any of the wiring or heating element and none of the air vents are plugged with debris or bug/bee nests I would see no issue in using it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it gas or electric?
Does it have mechanical or electronic controls/timer?
As mentioned, you should do a little cleaning, especially the vent tube.  The motor is usually protected from direct contact with rain, etc.
Electric:  If it has mechanical controls/timer, they will probably be okay.  You can test the timer without plugging it in.  When you do get ready to plug it in, turn off the circuit breaker first in the breaker panel that serves your house.  It should be a 2 pole 30 amp (usually twice as thick as a regular 15 or 20 amp breaker, in case it isn't marked.)  If you are not sure, you can get a non-contact voltage detector at Harbor Freight (less $$) or Home Depot and follow the instructions that come with it to be sure the plug is off.  If anything is shorted out, a 240 volt circuit can sometimes produce a fairly big spark.  So it's best to have the dryer plugged in, then turn on the breaker.  If it trips, it will pop but it won't hurt you.  If it doesn't, then turn start your dryer.
Make sure there is no burning smell that doesn't stop in just a very few minutes.  If it has electronic controls (touchscreen or soft touch panel buttons) check for water standing in the control panel or screen.  If there is water, it must be dried before connecting to power.
Gas:  Follow the above procedure before connecting gas line and turning the gas valve on.
If everything checks out okay, mix  equal amounts of dish-washing liquid & water (1:1 ratio) in a spray bottle.  Unplug the electric cord first.  Then connect gas line ant turn the gas valve on.  Spray the soapy water on all gas line connections and watch for bubbles.  If you see bubbles forming and inflating, that indicates a gas leak which must be fixed before proceeding.  If you don't know how, you might need a plumber, or at least someone with experience installing gas appliances.  If there are no leaks, plug it in and see if it works.
Gas or electric:  Check to be sure plenty of air is blowing out the vent.  If it is not a steady heavy flow, there is a clog or the fan motor is not running.  Check for blockage in the vent tube.  If the tube is clear but no air is moving. listen for the vent motor.  If it isn't turning, the dryer will need repair.
If you are not  sure about anything, you may ask more questions here via comment or call an appliance repair technician.